# Interact with shell python from another python

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, python

So my issue is the following:

I am using a version of python with my main libraries, to do something I need to interface with a program's python libraries. That program comes with a `.bat` file that sets up the variables and start python.

What I want to do from my main python is the following:

1. call the `.bat` file
2. From the python session created `import` my custom function
3. Send inputs to me custom functions (nested lists of strings mostly)
4. Stop the new python instance once the data is processed

How can such a thing be done from python? Should I anchor myself to the cmd prompt that is created in order to be able to send command to the new python instance? Would `os` or `subprocess` still be viable or would I need to create something like a powershell script to hand it all?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like something I've done in the past but not 100% certain but for example.... `Pid = os.getpid()` and `DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008` and `RunScript = "C:/Folder/Path/VerifyPID.cmd"` and `Cmd = ["cmd.exe", "/C", RunScript, sys.argv[0], TagName, host, RootPath, str(Pid)]` and `subprocess.Popen(Cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)`.... Maybe that will give you a rough idea but I have more examples if needed. Again I'm not 100% certain but potentially something along these lines will help.

Comment: Here's a link with more detail of what the code would look like to help clarify some potentially..... https://justpaste.it/663m5 .... The logic I use is a lot more complex using MySQL and PLC modules, etc. and calling functions and such.... maybe you will find helpful to at least get you pointed in a direction that may help. In the end, the batch script will accept arguments as `%~1` thru `%~5` essentially.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks! I'll look into it and see if it can be done that way.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Your cues helped for my solution, though I made some changes but the concept should be familiar to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I found a way to solve this as it appears that the subprocess is continuous it was quite straightforward.

Here is the code I used:

```
import subprocess as sb
from time import sleep

bat_file="C:\\...\\python_env.bat"

def executor(commands:list,mode=0):
    #initiate the process with the batch file
    proc=sb.Popen(bat_file, shell=False, stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE, stderr=sb.PIPE,)
    sleep(18)#Make sure python gets initiated
    if mode==0:
        for command in commands:#send commands
            proc.stdin.write((command+'\r\n').encode(encoding='utf-8',errors='strict'))
        outp=proc.communicate('print("done") \r\n'.encode(encoding='utf-8',errors='strict'),timeout=999999999)
    elif mode:
        commands="\r\n".join(commands)+"\r\n"
        outp=proc.communicate(commands.encode(encoding='utf-8',errors='strict'),timeout=999999999)
    #print all the console outputs
    print(outp[0].decode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict'))
    print('done')
```

I used stdin.write since it was the only way to send multiple commands instead of having to restart my python process for each instance, and I have also made a mode that concatenate everything together in order to all be handled by `communicate`.

As an example the input of the function could be :

```
commands=['import numpy as np','a=np.rand(3,2,1)','print(a)']
```

**EDIT_ important things to consider**

For anyone planning to rely on this, if you plan to send string there are 2 important things to consider!

1. You must find a way to preserve your quotation marks on each end of the string, here are the possible ways to preserve them `['"',"'",'\'',"\"","\'",'\"',"""'""",'''"''']`
2. Another thing that is important to consider is if you plan on using string that indicate paths or contain `\` in them, add `'r'` to the start of the string so the encode will interpret it as a raw string and not throw an error cause by `\` and the characters surrounding it.